# When To Use Only Principal Root

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt{4x^4-x}}{2x^2+3}$$

To solve this, I rewrote the limit by dividing both the numerator, which is $\sqrt{4x^4-x}$, and the denominator, which is ${2x^2+3}$, by $\sqrt{x^4}$ to get $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt{4-\frac{1}{x^3}}}{2+\frac{3}{x^2}}$. What I am confused by is that I know you only take the principal root if that square root is part of a function, but the $\sqrt{x^4}$ is not part of the function. I only used $\sqrt{x^4}$ to rewrite the function so I could more easily solve for the limit. If $\sqrt{x^4}$ is not part of the function, we care about both the positive and negative values of the square root, not just the principal root. So wouldn't I somehow have to divide the numerator by both +${x^2}$ and -${x^2}$ and the denominator by both +${x^2}$ and -${x^2}$? I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dividing top and bottom by $x^2 = |x^2| = \sqrt {x^4}$ is perfectly valid here - the square root always refers to taking the positive (or $0$) value. Dividing by $\sqrt{x^4}$ implies you're taking the positive square root, and your working is valid.

Comment: It might be worth emphasizing that $\sqrt{x^4} = |x^2| =x^2$, where the last equality is because $x^2 \geq 0$

Comment: @peek-a-boo Good idea, I've edited my answer.

Comment: But the square root only refers to taking the positive value if the square root is part of a function (b/c we can't have 2 different outputs for the same input). How is $\sqrt{x^4}$ part of the function? Its just an expression that was used to rewrite the function.

Comment: @user532874: What do you mean by “part of the function”? The expression $\sqrt{x^4}$ *always* means the non-negative root, no matter where it appears.

Comment: Then why does, for example, the quadratic formula have the plus and minus sign before the radical?